# Создать новый `drawable` объект или изменить существующий. Как правильнее?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Рисую кучу объектов на `canvas` в частности около 200 прямоугольников.
При этом создаю их прямо в `onDraw`.
Заметил что каждый раз при масштабировании запускается `invalidate` и следовательно `onDraw`. Т.е. все эти объекты фактически создаются заново.
Не лучше ли создать их заранее, а в `onDraw` просто рисовать их же с новыми размерами?

Этот вопрос в принципе и для любых объектов интересует. Например для `textView` и объектов своих собственных классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться с жизненным циклом `View`, мне помогла вот эта [статья](http://ndquangr.blogspot.ru/2013/04/android-view-lifecycle.html).

Что касается создания объектов - это вообще дорогостоящая операция, которую следует избегать.

Если вы используете Android Studio, то внутри метода `onDraw` у `View` она Вам подсказывает, что тут нужно избегать создания объектов, как огня, потому что данный метод вызывается достаточно часто и могут быть ощутимые последствия в виде лагов в UI.

Если создаваемое Вами изображение не будет меняться, то создайте его один раз при инициализации вашей `View`. Если есть какая-то логика изменения изображения, то лучше её построить так, чтобы в момент вызова `onDraw` изображение уже было готово.

Comment: Большое спасибо.