# Как идеально правильно работать с Handler-ом?

Tags: android

Для выполнения кода через секунду, например, делаю так

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> ..., 1000);
```

Но, а если этот код запускать слишком часто? Я слышал, что нужно хандлер "отпускать". Как правильно работать с хендлером?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашем случае, Вы постоянно создаёте новые объекты `Handler`, которые постепенно копятся, после чего они уничтожаются сборщиком мусора. Ключевой момент - уничтожение происходит не сразу, а потому на момент очистки таких объектов может накопиться много. Чем больше объектов вычищается из памяти за один раз, тем дольше это происходит. Чем больше одноразовых объектов в коде Вы создаёте, тем чаще на сцену выходит сборщик мусора. А значит и ощутимее становятся лаги в UI для пользователя.

Если хотите визуально это дело прочувствовать, то можете выделить место на экране, для постоянного вывода диагностической информации, собирая её примерно так:

```
private static final int MB = 1024 * 1024;
...
final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
final StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
info.append("\nTotal memory: ");
info.append(runtime.totalMemory() / MB);
info.append(" MB");
info.append("\nFree memory: ");
info.append(runtime.freeMemory() / MB);
info.append(" MB");
info.append("\nMax memory: ");
info.append(runtime.maxMemory() / MB);
info.append(" MB");
textView.setText(info.toString());
```

и обновляя раз в пол секунды.

Что касается использования самого `Handler`:

Как уже описывалось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666682/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-timer-%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-handler-%D0%B8-executor/666698#666698), с помощью `Handler`-a можно ставить блок кода в очередь на выполнение. А также `Handler` использует тот `Looper` поток, в котором он был создан, если Вы не передадите ему иной `Looper`.

А это означает следующее - если Вы регулярно используете `Handler` для выполнения задач в UI потоке, то убедитесь, что задачи не образуют непрерывную последовательность действий, которые заблокируют UI на ощутимое для пользователя количество времени. Также не забывайте, что для анимации используется `Looper` UI потока. (Про анимацию описывалось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663134/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/663222#663222)).
Если к этой куче добавить сборщик мусора, то эта троица может вызвать ощутимые лаги в UI.

Уточню - анимация сама по себе не нагружает UI настолько, чтобы назвать это нагрузкой. А потому в этой троице наличие анимации просто может послужить индикатором лагов, а не их первопричиной.

На практике не встречал перегруженный `Looper` одновременно всей троицей. Но если в Вашем проекте достаточно много кода ставится в очередь Looper-a, то могут быть ощутимые лаги в UI. А потому продумывайте архитектуру заранее.

P.S.: На всякий случай уточню, что под "отпускать" видимо имелось ввиду дать UI потоку время на взаимодействие с пользователем, чтобы сохранять интерактивность. Просто не выполняйте тяжелых блоков кода в UI.

P.P.S.: Не создавайте каждый раз новые объекты для регулярного выполнения одних и тех же задач. Используйте старые. ([Немного нужных слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653127/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-drawable-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5/653158#653158) про пересоздание объектов).

Answer (score 0):

Если ты запускаешь таймер именно так, то для каждого вызова ты создаешь новый `Handler` и не держишь на него ссылку, т.е. по сути новый хендлер будет уничтожен сразу (почти) после выполнения кода внутри него